# Non-baseline AVC video profile is not supported by Android OS

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, libavcodec

I have been using the "[cordova-plugin-video-editor](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor)" plugin to reduce the size/quality of my videos before uploading them to the server.

The plugin works correctly on most Android phones and no worries on iOS.

But on recent Android phones it happens that it crashes.
I reproduce this error with a Xiaomi RedMi Note 7 under Android 9.

I have this mistake:

> net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.InvalidOutputFormatException:

Non-baseline AVC video profile is not supported by Android OS, actual

> profile_idc: 100

Here are the characteristics of the video:

```
H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10)(avc1)
1920x1080
Planar 4:2:0 YUV
ITU-R BT.601 (50 Hz)

MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)
48000Hz
32bits
```

After several searches I can't find a solution but still some leads like :

- https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder/issues/72
- https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder/pull/73#issuecomment-475871771

Today I can't come to any other conclusion than to have to create my own plugin to use another Android library that is compatible with new video formats.

I must admit that I don't like this solution too much and that's why I call on the community. What can I try next?

### Solved

It was indeed the plugin dependency that was not compatible with the new codecs.

So I fork the plugin on my GitHub and then modify the code part that transcodes the video. Now I use this library instead of the old one: https://github.com/tangpeng/VideoCompressor

You can see the changes in the commits of this repo:
https://github.com/Eblancho/cordova-plugin-video-editor

I do not advise you to use it for your projects because it is not 100% tested / compatible with all phones, it is very recent as a change.

In addition to that, unlike the previous version which allowed to choose the height/width, bitrates and other things, my version the calculations:

```
newHeight = videoHeight / 2;
newWidth = videoWidth / 2;
bitrates = (newHeight / 2) * (newWidth / 2) * 10;
```

### A new problem has emerged

This new problem is not a side-effect due to my modifications because it also appears on the old versions, I just thought it was also related to transcoding.

Now, when I open the camera to record my video, as soon as I want to close the intent to go back to the Cordova mainActivity, the application restarts.

I don't think that's really the topic for discussion, so I'm going to create a new question to better separate my problems.

Comment: Hi, I too have the same non-baseline problem.  Can you please update your question with an accepted answer, also explaining HOW you replaced the transcoding library in the code, and how you chose the replacement? Thanks